# Tikzit library confuse

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdftex, pdf

I'm using TikZiT to draw graphs with nodes and edges. How to translate that picture to the pdf version of my LaTeX document if possible. There is a code below picture in TikZiT which I copy-paste to LaTeX document but it doesn't show the picture in pdf format and I don't know what exactly I'm missing here. I only have `\usepackage{tikz}` in preamble of LaTeX document.

example of TikZiT code that I copy paste to LaTeX:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node [style=new style 0] (0) at (-10, 2) {};
        \node [style=new style 0] (1) at (-10, 0) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
        \draw [bend left=90, looseness=2.75] (0) to (1);
        \draw [bend right=90, looseness=2.75] (0) to (1);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: It's your 4th question, maybe try to consider the recommendation here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228.

Comment: To expand on the comment above: what does the rest of your document look like? Did you include all the necessary elements, a documentclass, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` etc? Do you get any error messages, or wrong output, or no output?

Comment: This code is the code taken from the picture drawn using tikzit software. I could not implement this code in latex.

Comment: That much is clear, the question is what you have done to compile this as a LaTeX document. If you didn't add anything except `\usepackage{tikz}` then that is the cause of the issue, a LaTeX document needs the structure that I mentioned in my previous comment (a documentclass, begin/end document). If you don't add that then your document does not compile. In that case you do get an error message when you try to compile, that is why I asked if you get any error messages.

Comment: If you want to read more about the basic elements of a LaTeX document you can look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure for example.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://tikzit.github.io) you may need something like `\usepackage{tikzit}
\input{sample.tikzstyles}
\input{sample.tikzdefs}` in the preamble. (Of course, you will also need the package and the sample files, which seem not to be on the standard TeX installations, perhaps for a reason.)

Comment: Should I install the tikzit package?

Comment: I made a drawing with reference to this link.  https://tikzit.github.io/#styles    But I couldn't implement this texmaker. Do u understand my issue?

Comment: The documentation says: "TikZ style files have a very simple format. They are just a list of `\tikzstyle` commands." So no, try to use some other tool.

Answer (score 1):

With this preamble you can compile it without changes via pdflatex.
(Preamble taken from https://github.com/tikzit/tikzit/blob/master/tex/sample/tikzit.sty and tested with MiKTeX)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,shapes.misc}

\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfsetlayers{background,edgelayer,nodelayer,main}
\tikzstyle{none}=[inner sep=0mm]
%\tikzstyle{new style 0}=[inner sep=0mm]
\tikzset{new style 0/.style={circle,draw}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node [style=new style 0] (0) at (-10, 2) {};
        \node [style=new style 0] (1) at (-10, 0) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
        \draw [bend left=90, looseness=2.75] (0) to (1);
        \draw [bend right=90, looseness=2.75] (0) to (1);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is pretty straightforward to understand and the picture it should produce is very simple. But it uses layers (at least two layers here) which you could get rid of, like I did below. There's also a style defined (which is not provided in your code). Let's assume it's a circle shape for the nodes, you may tell us what you intended in the first place.

[image: Try 1]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}


\tikzset{new style 0/.style={circle,draw}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [style=new style 0] (0) at (-10, 2) {};
            \node [style=new style 0] (1) at (-10, 0) {};
    
    
            \draw [bend left=90, looseness=2.75] (0) to (1);
            \draw [bend right=90, looseness=2.75] (0) to (1);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Maybe this could be a starting point for you to understand how to implement these things into a LaTeX compiler.

Answer (score 0):

In the first was not entirely clear what is your problem (I didn't figured out why you use   `\begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}` and `\begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}`; it may be specific of `tikzit` to which I'm not familiar).

If you like to have pure `tikz` code for picture, than you can (also) try the following solution, where nodes positions are determined by help of the `positioning` Ti*k*Z library:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{new style 0/.style={circle,draw}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 20mm and 0mm,
   arr/.style = {bend left=90, looseness=2.75},
     C/.style = {circle, draw}  
                        ]
\node (n1) [C] {};
\node (n2) [C, below=of n1] {};
%
\draw (n1)  to [arr]    (n2)
      (n2)  to [arr]    (n1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]